# Setting and displaying date ranges extracted from filenames in the header

Tags: macros, header-footer, fancyhdr, loops, datetime

I already asked a related question about this topic some months ago. However, I have a project with this structure:

```
Project:
 |- main.tex
 |
 |- pages
     |- 20230101.tex
     |- 20230102.tex
     |- ...
```

I included all the files under `pages` in `main.tex` using this `for` loop (a static solution but filenames have a fixed length, etc.):

```
\foreach \year in {2023, 2024} {
    \foreach \month in {01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12} {
        \foreach \day in {01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, ..., 31} {
            \edef\fileName{pages/\year\month\day}
            \IfFileExists{\fileName}{
               \getfiledate{\day}{\month}{\year}
               \include{\fileName}
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

`\getfiledate{\day}{\month}{\year}` is a command used to store and display the date on the top right corner of the page:

```
\newcommand{\getfiledate}[3]{\renewcommand{\getfiledate}{\dayofweekname{#1}{#2}{#3}\ #1/#2/#3}}
```

As file names may suggest, the creation of a new file does not imply the end of the previous section/chapter, so using `include` causes an unwanted page break. I tried replacing it with `input` but the compiler throws an error if two short files end up on the same page. My goal is now to show a range of dates (from the first and the last file) when two or more files are embedded on the same page. For example, if there are three files, namely `20230103.tex`, `20230102.tex` and `20230103.tex`, all containing one line, the resulting page should have this header:

```
Sunday 01/01/2023 - Tuesday 03/02/2023
```

and the three lines one below the other. If the files-per-page ratio is 1:1 (i.e. files longer than one page), then the header should remain as it is now (with only one date).

Do you think this is possibile? I leave you here a MWE if you want to give it a try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor, fancyhdr, datetime}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\getfiledate}

\newcommand{\getfiledate}[3]{\renewcommand{\getfiledate}{\dayofweekname{#1}{#2}{#3}\ #1/#2/#3}}

\begin{document}

\foreach \year in {2023, 2024} {
    \foreach \month in {01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12} {
        \foreach \day in {01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, ..., 31} {
            \edef\fileName{pages/\year\month\day}
            \IfFileExists{\fileName}{
               \getfiledate{\day}{\month}{\year}
               \include{\fileName}
            }
        }
    }  
}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance to everyone.